# Centrifugal acceleration in projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, centrifugal-force

In projectile motion, let's take any point on it's trajectory i.e. we are talking about an instance where the particle is. Then, is there any centrifugal force acting in the opposite direction to the force which is acting along the radius of curvature?

Answer (score 0):

The presence of a centrifugal force only applies when looking at the system from a rotating reference frame. So, if you are watching your projectile while on a Ferris wheel, for example, then you would need to include a centrifugal force (among other fictitious forces) to explain the motion of the projectile.

If you are just watching the projectile from an inertial reference frame, say you just threw a ball from your stationary house's window, then you do not need to include a centrifugal force. Ignoring air resistance there is just a single force acting on the projectile: gravity.